# Access value of listbox assigned through jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am assgining values to the listbox through jquery. After assgining the values on button click event, i am not able to get the items in the list box. It shows empty item list. I am able to get the values through hidden field, but is there any better way around?

Thanks

**Update**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {   
    $("#imgbtnRight,#imgbtnLeft").click(function(event) {
        var id = $(event.target).attr("id");            
        var selectFrom = id == "imgbtnRight" ? "[id*=lbAllStores]" : "[id*=lbIncludedStores]";            
        var moveTo = id == "imgbtnRight" ? "[id*=lbIncludedStores]" : "[id*=lbAllStores]";
        var selectedItems = $(selectFrom + " option:selected").toArray();
        $(moveTo).append(selectedItems);           
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you at least provide some code of what you have done so far?

Comment: Please at least show your HTML/ascx/aspx code as well as a hint of how you're adding the value in jQuery.

Comment: The scenario is, I have 2 list box and I am moving Item between these two using jquey like <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $("[id*=btnRight]").click(function(event) { var selectedItems = $("[id*=lbStores] option:selected").length; alert(selectedItems); }); }); </script> And I want the values of both this list box, on click of Save button to save in DB.

Comment: @NaveenKrishna: I have put your code to the question. You can go to edit in question and do any changes if you need !!!

Comment: See @StevenHunt below - he's explained what I believe to be the problem.  A hidden field is probably the easiest way round it.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and answers. I just wanted to know if any other method can be used other than hidden field. Looks like there isn't any other than  jQuery ajax() function. And i guess to continue with the hidden field is the easiest for my current requirment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page posts back to the server, the contents of the DOM are not sent back to ASP .net. The only information from the page is contained in the form elements (think `<input>` tags) submitted to the server, such as hidden fields. The only other way to solve this is to start using ajax to send the data back to the server instead of a postback.

Comment: Well deciphered.  I think you've hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Right. The problem is that asp .net and the server-side are not aware of the changes. You should probably look into using the jQuery ajax() function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Then, in asp .net, you could build a request handler (ashx file) to handle your database reads/writes.